# I changed my Nikon DSLR settings and now images are blurry — what to do?

Tags: nikon, dslr, camera-settings, blur

I am absolutely new in photography. I own a Nikon D3300. My camera was working fine until I did some manual tuning to aperture, shutter speed, and many other things.

After those changes, my pictures are blurry when I try to zoom in. When I zoom out to the maximum level then 70% of the time the image is sharp. Also, in excellent light condition, it works fine with little zoom but when I try to zoom more it again becomes blurry.

I have no idea what I have done and how I can fix it. It behaves same in auto mode too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Reset your settings as described in the manual on page 224](http://download3.nikonimglib.com/archive1/Wywwt00lh46s0109T7E089fAaV06/D3300RM_%28En%2902.pdf)

> menu button -> shooting menu: "yes" for "Reset Shooting Menu"

Additionally, check your manual focus settings as found on page 83 of the same manual.